# Is it possible to set up an event listener in the browser to capture values returned from res.render?

Tags: node.js, express, azure-ad-b2c

**Desired Behaviour**

I have a Node.js/Express application that uses Azure AD B2C to login.

I want to return values returned from the server-side, OAuth style, login to the browser and save them in browser cookies (using [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)).

I want to do this so that I can use these values in various UI functionality.

However, the only thing that currently goes back to the browser is via [res.render()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render) (using a [simple template engine](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/developing-template-engines.html)):

```js
res.render('index', { page_html: my_page_html, some_other_value: 'hello'  });
```

Essentially, `res.render` returns an html file to the browser which contains placeholder values that are replaced by the variables passed into `res.render`.

Is it possible to set up an event listener in the browser to capture values returned from `res.render`?

Or, if that is not possible, is there any other way to 'push' a value to the frontend (in parallel with `res.render`) so that it could be handled by frontend code?

**Context**

Previously, in other projects, I have made Ajax requests from the frontend to the backend and therefore had easy access to what was returned from the server, which I could then use in response handler logic and save in browser cookies etc.

However, in this instance, I am doing all my login logic from the backend code and therefore there is no specific request from frontend to backend, and no response handler in the frontend.

So I am not sure how I can pass values received in the backend (after login) to the frontend.

The authentication process follows a common OAuth work flow:

- User hits a protected endpoint - in this case the 'root' endpoint (i.e:  `/`)
- User is forwarded to identity provider to login (in this case Azure AD B2C)
- On successful login, user is forwarded to a redirect URI, and authorisation code is received in server-side code
- Server-side code uses authorisation code to request an access token
- Access token is saved in `req.session.accessToken`
- On subsequent requests to protected endpoints, if `req.session.accessToken` is present, the request can proceed

This project does not use any JavaScript framework (eg React, Angular).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply set a cookie on the response by using the callback of the `res.render()` method and call [`res.cookie()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie) inside of it before calling `res.send()`.

The browser will save the cookie as expected, which you can then access using `js-cookie`.

For reference, you need to do something like this

```js
res.render('index', { /* locals */ }, function (err, html) {
  res.cookie('key', 'value');
  res.send(html);
);
```

Comment: Would you be able to post an example of a `res.render()` that includes a callback that runs `res.cookie()`?  I am using the following and I cannot see any cookie in the browser (and the browser 'loading' icon seems to keep spinning):  `res.render('index', { key_01:  "some value", key_02:  "some other value"  } ,  (err, html) => {  console.log("sanity check - is anything working?"); res.cookie('myFantasicCookie', 'I AM A COOKIE VALUE!')  } );`

Comment: Update:  I added `res.send()` at the end of the callback, and now the cookie is set in the browser, but my page is not rendered at all.

Comment: Hmm, I changed `res.send()` to `res.send(html)` and now the page is rendering and the cookie is visible (the cookie value seems to be html encoded, ie:  `I%20AM%20A%20COOKIE%20VALUE!`).  Not sure if that is the correct way to add `res.cookie()` to the `res.render()` callback or not, but it seems to be working.

Comment: Yes. That is correct. I've added a code snippet for clarity. The [`res.cookie()` docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie) has an `encode` function that defaults to `encodeURIComponent` which I believe is to ensure that it is compliant with [RFC 6265](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265)